# Using Spring cloud config in multi application architecture

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am currently using Spring external configuration by creating a config server, config client and a Git repository with property files. Is there any way to use this config server for multiple applications?

My Current Architecture:

1. Created a Git repository with config files.
2. Created a Config Server which connects to the above Git repository for property files.
3. Created a Client (Spring boot application) which connects to the config server to load the properties.

When there is a change in any of the property files, I am invoking the refresh method of config client to refresh the properties. If there are multiple applications using the same config server and git repository for property files, what should be the approach to refresh all the properties without invoking the /refresh method of all the applications?

I tried /refresh of the config server but it doesn't refresh the properties as they are loaded during the application startup.

Comment: You can use the `spring-cloud-config-monitor` and spring cloud bus to do distributed refresh. What version are you using that `/refresh` doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @spencergibb, thank you will check that, can you provide me more information or some links to refer?
/refresh of the config client is working fine but what I meant was that /refresh of the config server is not refreshing the client properties. I am using Edgware.RELEASE version for spring-cloud-dependencies.

Comment: Are you using the POST method to send the request to /refresh?